# How to achieve parallelism in Circle CI when test jobs are running from fastlane fastfile?

Tags: parallel-processing, circleci, fastlane, xcuitest

I'm stuck at a point where I want to divide the XCUItestcases(total of 40) that I have for my project and run them in parallel(10 testcases run /one parallel executor) in CI. All my ui-tests path are there in fastfile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's funny you would post this today. I've spent 4-5 days on this subject over the last few months with the bulk of that being this week. I summarized my findings using various methods yesterday at https://www.iammike.org/2021/03/04/xcuitest-circleci-and-parallelization/.

The short of it is that this is very unreliable and not worth the effort. The problem is CircleCI doesn't seem to handle the load from XCUITest very well and more or less chokes on it, causing intermittent failures.

I'm awaiting feedback from CircleCI support and will update this appropriately.

Comment: Yes I'm having the same issue. Thats why wanted to check for running tests in parallel to see if that avoids crash in CI. Circle CI fails some of our XCUITests as well inconsistently. The reason of that failure is mostly because of simulator crash as below. 

Failed to get matching snapshots: Lost connection to the application (pid 7990). (Underlying Error: Couldn’t communicate with a helper application. Try your operation again. If that fails, quit and relaunch the application and try again. The connection to service on pid 0 created from an endpoint was invalidated.)

Comment: Yeah, that's a system hang as opposed to an XCUITest hang. I don't know that upgrading to a "large" resource type will help you there, but it was the trick to get my tests running even close to reliably when I was seeing XCUITest specific slowness/failures.

Comment: Just heard back from support and it's officially not supported.